# Why is HTML I put in a Mongodb document as JSON displaying as text on the webpage?

Tags: html, json, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo database with a document that contains some html in it, and when I try to take it and put it on a webpage, it just displays as the actual text and not the html. Here is the json with the html:

```
db.games.insert({
  title: "Minecraft",
  background: "/images/minecraft.jpg",
  code: "<div id=\"gameBackround\" class=\"col-lg-2 popular-games view view-first\" style=\"background-image:url( /images/gameArt/minecraft.jpg )\"> <div class=\"mask\"> <h2>Minecraft</h2> <p>Amount of groups playing this title now: 11,075</p> <a href=\"#\" class=\"info\">Join Lobby</a> </div> </div> <style>  </style>"
})
```

and here is how I display it on the page:

```
<template name="example">  
  {{code}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use should use triple curly braces to escape html code returned from a helper.

```
<template name="example">  
    {{{code}}}
</template>
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/xGYrKJ) is an example.